# How to repeat a matrix on it's side?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the following matrix in Mathematica:

```
mat = {{0,0,1,1}, {0,1,0,1}}
```

I want to repeat this matrix N number of times on the side.

For example if N = 3 then the output should be:

$$
 \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Please post *Mathematica* syntax/code,  not TeX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Join[..., 2]` will do it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code for your case (and assuming `n` is not too large):

```
Join[##, 2] & @@ ConstantArray[mat, n]
```

Comment: An alternative to the last expression might be `Join[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[mat, n], 2]`

Answer (score 8):

Another way ([`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)):

```
ArrayFlatten[{ConstantArray[mat, n]}, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach would be

```
mat = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
Row[ConstantArray[Rotate[mat // MatrixForm, -Pi/2], 3]]
```

[image: onitsside]

... I'll see myself out now.

Comment: Cheeky. :P ${}$

Answer (score 4):

I am a novice user so please forgive me if this is a bit clunky!  Using `Transpose` and `ArrayReshape`

```
mat = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
n = 11;    
ArrayReshape[Transpose[Table[mat, {n}]], Dimensions[mat] {1, n}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: This answer seems to work but would be more compelling, if applied to the `mat` in the question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - thanks for your advice.  I was playing around with a few different shapes of `mat` to see if the solution worked and ended up pasting in one of the other ones!

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, {#2, #2}} & @@ Dimensions[#], "Periodic"] & @  mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or something more general:

```
ArrayPad[#, 
   {{0, 1}, {1, 2}} {{#, #}, {#2, #2}} & @@ Dimensions[#], 
   "Periodic"
] & @ mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`PadRight[]`/`PadLeft[]` can also be used in this case:

```
mat = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}; n = 3;
PadRight[ConstantArray[{}, Length[mat]], Dimensions[mat] {1, n}, mat]
   {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

**KroneckerProduct**

```
kpF = KroneckerProduct[{ConstantArray[1, #2 ]}, #] &;
```

**SparseArray and Band**

```
saF = SparseArray[(Band[{1, 1}, {1, #2} Dimensions[#], {1,1}] -> #)] &;
```

Examples:

```
mat = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}};
saF[mat, 5] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
kpF[mat, 3] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
mat = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

Using `ReplicateLayer` (new in 11.1)

```
Join @@@ Round @ Transpose @ ReplicateLayer[4] @ mat
```

returns

```
{{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
 {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}
```

Comment: it's a (+1) from me, but to make it exactly like the desired result, I think it should be `ReplicateLayer[3]`, right? Otherwise, the dimensions don't match. Good stuff nonetheless!!!

Comment: Thanks, bmf, I took the desired output from the question. Maybe `n + 1` if we imitate the question

Comment: oh yes. of course. I was comparing to some other answers and got confused. Silly mistake on my part. Don't bother :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
mat1 = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

Using `Table` and `GatherBy`:

```
Flatten /@ GatherBy[Catenate@Table[mat1, {4}]]

(*{{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}*)
```

Using `GatherBy` to address this problem is possible as long as the matrix doesn't have all its elements equal, but we can generalize this strategy using `Partition` as shown below:

```
repeatMat[mat_?MatrixQ, n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{repmat},
    repmat = Catenate @ Table[mat, {n}];
    If[MatchQ[Flatten @ repmat, {Repeated[m_Integer]}],
            Map[Flatten, Partition[repmat, n]],
            Map[Flatten, GatherBy @ repmat]
        ]
   ];

mat2 = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};

repeatMat[mat1, 4] === Join[mat1, mat1, mat1, mat1, 2]

(*True*)

repeatMat[mat2, 4] === Join[mat2, mat2, mat2, mat2, 2]

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since @kglr already used [**`KroneckerProduct`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html), I am demonstrating a solution that uses [**`TensorProduct`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html) + [`**ArrayFlatten**`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

```
 = ArrayFlatten@TensorProduct[{ConstantArray[1, #2]}, #] &;
```

and then

```
[mat, 3]
```

gives

> `{{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0, 1}}`