# How to expand a MxM matrix with replicates of itself and drop some of the rows and cols periodically?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I expand a 2d-matrix with dimensions **x,x** (e.g. `mat = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }}`) with replicates of `mat` into `matTimes100` with dimensions **100*x,100*x**? 
I tried `Join[ mat, mat, mat, <97>, 2 ]` which works nicely and would give me dimensions **100*x,x**. However, I do not want to manually insert `mat` 100 times into Join[].

How to do that automatically? `Join[ Table[ mat, { 1, 100 } ], 2 ]` does not work, since it delivers `Join[`**{**`mat, mat, mat, <97>`**}**`, 2 ]`.

**EDIT:**

On request, I try to clarify my question. In addition, I try to figure out, what exactly I'm trying to do.

Let's assume a `MxM` Matrix with `M = 3`:

```
mat={{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Reverse@mat//TableForm
```

Now I would like to make a larger `NxN` matrix out of it with some of the rows and cols dropped in a periodic manner. I tried to visualize my purpose. In the MWE below I choose `num = 2` with `N = M + num * ( M - 1 )`.  The dropped rows/cols are indicated by the blue lines.

Thanks for your hints!!

[image]

Comment: To clarify, is your goal a 100*x by 100*x matrix or a 100*x by x matrix? Also, you could try `Join[Sequence@@Table[mat,100],2]`

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixAndTensorOperations.html, Ctrl+F "replicate"

Comment: @Quantum_Oli my goal is a 100*x by 100*x matrix. I just tried to outline my first approach first replicating the rows and than to repeat that with the cols.

Comment: Closely related then: [how-to-repeat-a-matrix-on-its-side](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103834/how-to-repeat-a-matrix-on-its-side)

Comment: @rahul `PadRight` looks very nice. This will solve my Problem, thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to create a 100X100 block matrix, where every block is equal to `mat`? If that's the case (my answer below is another approach to get that), it would be good to edit it into the question, since it seems unclear to some, what you want.

Comment: I'd disagree with the duplicate vote, since that question is quite a bit narrower in scope, as such, so are its answers.

Comment: The dropping of rows and columns is shifting the goalposts quite a bit.

Comment: Consider `Drop[Array[Reverse[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}] &, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, ArrayFlatten[{##}] &], {3, 6, 3}, {4, 7, 3}]`.

Comment: Related: [(1633)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1633/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using `Fold`

```
newmat = Fold[Join[#1, #2, 2] &, mat, ConstantArray[mat, 100]];
MatrixForm@newmat
```

[image]

Another method, using `ArrayReshape` and `Transpose`

```
ArrayReshape[Transpose[ConstantArray[mat, 100]], {2, 200}]
```

Another method using `ArrayPad`

```
ArrayPad[mat, {{0, 0}, {0, 200}}, mat]
```

Comment: These do not produce a 200 x 200 array, which seems to be what the OP is after, but the question is worded with conflicting statements. I *think* they're after `ArrayPad[mat, {{0, 198}, {0, 198}}, "Periodic"]`, but beats me...

Comment: Based on the fact that they said `Join[ mat, mat, mat, <97>, 2 ]` would work perfectly, that wasn't how I interpreted the question, because that would give a 2 by 200 matrix

Comment: Yeah, the "100*n,100*n" is at odds with that - like I said, beats me.

Comment: Sometimes I try to answer the question quick and don't wait for them to clarify the question.

Comment: @JasonB your answer helped me. I'm looking for a 200 x 200 array, but I'm able to help myself with your answer -> JasonB.

Comment: @ciao you're right. Maybe the question is not asked properly. I think this usually comes with the fact of not being a native speaker...

Answer (score 3):

I like this one:

```
ArrayFlatten[Table[mat, 100, 100]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PadRight[#, {10, 10} Dimensions[#], "Periodic"] & @ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly shorter, you can do `PadRight[#, {10, 10} Dimensions[#], #] &@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = Drop[ArrayFlatten[ConstantArray[Reverse@#, {#2, #2}]], 3;; ;;3, 4;; ;;3] &

f2 = Drop[KroneckerProduct[ConstantArray[1, {#2 , #2}], Reverse@ #], 3;; ;;3, 4;; ;;3] &


mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
n = 5;
f1[mat,n] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1[mat, n] == f2[mat, n]
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Band`

```
dim = Length[mat]
SparseArray[(Band[{dim # - 1, dim # - 1}] -> mat) & /@ Range[3]];
% // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

you can do the same thing with `Outer` also

```
Outer[Times, IdentityMatrix[3], mat] // ArrayFlatten;
% // MatrixForm
```

You can modify the first argument depending on how you want to replicate your matrix. For example if want to get Kuba's answer replace `IdentityMatrix[3]` by `ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}]`.

If you want to put your matrix row wise, then use `Band[{1, dim # - 1}]`.

```
dim = Length[mat]
SparseArray[(Band[{1, dim # - 1}] -> mat) & /@ Range[3]];
% // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
>  3 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$