# Adding columns to an existing table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two tables that look something like-

```
39.3278 2990.3 4503.98 0 -1859.37
35.7833 3014.8 1281.98 0 -3497.95
```

and

```
0.0255 28.6 -9.954 -2.612
0.0724 28.7 -1.031 -1.435
```

I am trying to generate a grand table by joining these two tables that should look something like this-

```
39.3278 2990.3 4503.98 0 -1859.37 0.0255 28.6 -9.954 -2.612
35.7833 3014.8 1281.98 0 -3497.95 0.0724 28.7 -1.031 -1.435
```

The code that I am using is-

```
data1 = {{39.3278, 2990.3, 4503.98, 0, -1859.37}, {35.7833, 3014.8, 
1281.98, 0, -3497.95}};
data2 = {{0.0255, 28.6, -9.954, -2.612}, {0.0724, 
28.7, -1.031, -1.435}};
data = Transpose@Join[Transpose@data1, data2];
TableForm[data]
```

But above code is showing the error that levels can not be transposed. What is the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: At least closely related: [103834](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103834/5478), [67423](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67423/5478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d1 = {{39.3278`, 2990.3`, 4503.98`, 0, -1859.37`}, {35.7833`, 3014.8`, 1281.98`, 
    0, -3497.95`}};
d2 = {{0.0255`, 28.6`, -9.954`, -2.612`}, {0.0724`, 28.7`, -1.031`, -1.435`}};

Join[d1, d2, 2]
```

> ```
> {{39.3278, 2990.3, 4503.98, 0, -1859.37, 0.0255, 28.6, -9.954, -2.612},
>  {35.7833, 3014.8, 1281.98, 0, -3497.95, 0.0724, 28.7, -1.031, -1.435}}
> ```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121522/5478

Comment: @Kuba Hm... I did not mean to be capricious.  I did not remember that instance.  Recommended action?

Comment: I know, happens to me too. Don't know yet, this surely has be asked many times and will be, maybe we should think about some cleaning in list-manipulation faqs. Since "elegant operations" is already a multiquestion guideline maybe it would not harm to add some more common activities.

Comment: Duplicate from early 2012: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-matrix

Comment: @Mike That is not a simple duplicate however, unfortunately.  Yes, an answer exists within but not one that is likely to be noticed and understood by a beginner as it is complicated by the need to convert rows to columns. It *is* the first Q&A I linked from [(121522)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121522/5478) but there too I did not think it an ideal duplicate as I did not mark that one as such.